Density of the maximum of a conditioned standard Brownian motion in [0, 1] time interval
Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion. How do you find the density of $\max_{0 \leq t \leq 1} ((B_t)_{0 \leq t \leq 1} | B_1 = x)$?
The hint is to analyse this joint: $P(N \geq y, B_1 \in (x \pm \epsilon))$ but I don't see what properties of a standard Brownian motion to use.

What is $N$ here?

This question is a duplicate of: Conditioned Maximum of Brownian Motion.
